# Year to date vs Year to date last year | Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, date

I would like to calculate the Year to date (YTD) value for this year and compare it to the same period last year in Pandas. My df looks like this:

```
Month   Product A   Product B
2015-01-01  24  62
2015-02-01  46  24
2015-03-01  30  70
2015-04-01  26  51
2015-05-01  34  42
2015-06-01  45  35
2015-07-01  25  13
2015-08-01  98  95
2015-09-01  6   81
2015-10-01  93  38
2015-11-01  98  59
2015-12-01  98  1
2016-01-01  67  42
2016-02-01  72  34
2016-03-01  7   6
2016-04-01  19  24
2016-05-01  82  38
2016-06-01  15  79
2016-07-01  49  83
2016-08-01  97  56
```

The two values i am after for product A are 
YTD = 408 and YTD SPLY = 328 (Sum Jan-Aug 2016, Sum Jan-Aug 2015).
When a new month is added to the df, i would like the formula to calculate Jan-Sep and so on.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want but it looks like you want to take the cumulative sum for each year.

```
df[['A_cumsum', 'B_cumsum']] = df.resample('A', on='Month').transform('cumsum')


        Month  Product A  Product B  A_cumsum  B_cumsum
0  2015-01-01         24         62        24        62
1  2015-02-01         46         24        70        86
2  2015-03-01         30         70       100       156
3  2015-04-01         26         51       126       207
4  2015-05-01         34         42       160       249
5  2015-06-01         45         35       205       284
6  2015-07-01         25         13       230       297
7  2015-08-01         98         95       328       392
8  2015-09-01          6         81       334       473
9  2015-10-01         93         38       427       511
10 2015-11-01         98         59       525       570
11 2015-12-01         98          1       623       571
12 2016-01-01         67         42        67        42
13 2016-02-01         72         34       139        76
14 2016-03-01          7          6       146        82
15 2016-04-01         19         24       165       106
16 2016-05-01         82         38       247       144
17 2016-06-01         15         79       262       223
18 2016-07-01         49         83       311       306
19 2016-08-01         97         56       408       362
```

Comment: I get the error message 'The grouper name Month is not found' when i try this. Is the code different when the Month variable is the index in the df?

Comment: When the Month is used as an index, i can simply drop the "on='Month'" code. Thank you.